# GCSfuse "Unknown bucket" when Gcloud can see it. Service account seems correct

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcsfuse

I'm trying to mount a bucket to my gcp instance, but it fails both with a newly created bucket and my existing one. I can see the buckets with gsutil ls, and I can copy files to them with gsutil cp.

However, when I try to mount using GCSFuse, the following happens:

```
xxx@downloader:~$ gcsfuse gs://yyy bdir/
Using mount point: /home/xxx/bdir
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: setUpBucket: OpenBucket: Unknown bucket 
"gs://yyy"
```

Permissions seem to be OK.

```
xxx@downloader:~$ gcloud iam service-accounts list
NAME                                    EMAIL                                               DISABLED
Compute Engine default service account  xxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com  False
```

This service account is listed as a user with Owner access for the bucket. For the project, the account is Editor and Storage Admin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

It seems that one should specify the bucket name and not a bucket URL.

For example:

```
gcsfuse yyy bdir/
```

instead of ...

```
gcsfuse gs://yyy bdir/
```

Comment: Glad that helped.  You may want to consider flagging the question as answered.  This is used by good folks looking to help and searching for questions that need work.  If the answer given is satisfactory to you and you need nothing further then flagging it answered can help others looking for assistance.